# Redirecting to a laravel route link on button click

Tags: javascript, laravel

On button click. I want page to redirect to a laravel route url using a separate script.

Below is my code:

```
<button id="myButton">Home</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
    location.href = "{{ route('customer.wishlist.remove',$item->id) }}";
};
```

onclick it directly showing the route link in the browser tab.

Please help me where iam going wrong.
thank you.

Comment: Try with : window.location.href

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<button id="myButton">Home</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
    window.location.href = "{{ route('customer.wishlist.remove',$item->id) }}";
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried but is same. its not redirecting to the laravel route url

Answer (score 1):

**pass CSRF token and write window.location.href in your code**

```
    <button id="myButton">Home</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
        window.location.href = "{{ route('customer.wishlist.remove',$item->id) }}";
    };
```

**or**

```
<a href="{{ url('/path/' . $item->id . '/path(edit like)') }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right">BUttonn naame</a>
```

Comment: Thank you @PHP for your answer but its not working. As you mentioned pass CSRF. whats this  CSRF token. As iam newbie to laravel please assist me on this.